# date format error in swift with month & year

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter

Wrong value recived when decoding date in swift

```
  let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "LLL YYYY"
    dateFormatterGet.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")
    dateFormatterGet.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    
    if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: "Mar 2020") {
        print(dateFormatterGet.string(from: date))// Prints Dec 2019
print(date)//2019-12-22 00:00:00 +0000

    } else {
       print("There was an error decoding the string")
    }
```

it prints 2019-12-22 00:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 1):

Should the dateFormat be `dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "LLL yyyy"`?

This prints

```
Mar 2020
2020-03-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

in my console.